# Optimizing custom canvas drawing on flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a custom canvas that sits as stack on top of my other widgets.

The PainterPoint is as follows:

```
class PainterPoint {
  bool isEnd;
  Color color;
  Offset offset;
  double strokeSize;
  BlendMode blendMode;

  PainterPoint({
    required this.offset,
    required this.isEnd,
    this.strokeSize = 2,
    this.color = Colors.blue,
    this.blendMode = BlendMode.color,
  });
}
```

And finally the BrushPainter is as:

```
class BrushPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<PainterPoint> points;

  BrushPainter({required this.points});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    Path path = Path();
    bool isNewLine = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      final currentPoint = points[i];

      if (currentPoint.isEnd) {
        if (!isNewLine) {
          canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
          path.reset();
          isNewLine = true;
        }
      } else {
        if (isNewLine) {
          path.moveTo(currentPoint.offset.dx, currentPoint.offset.dy);
          isNewLine = false;
        } else {
          path.lineTo(currentPoint.offset.dx, currentPoint.offset.dy);
        }
        if (currentPoint.isEraser) {
          paint.color = Colors.transparent;
          paint.blendMode = BlendMode.clear;
        } else {
          paint.color = currentPoint.color;
          paint.blendMode = BlendMode.color;
        }

        paint.strokeWidth = currentPoint.strokeSize;
      }
    }

    if (!isNewLine) {
      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

But when I try to draw something the experience get laggy way too quickly. Even after a few points(after about 80-90 points) drawn the entire thing lags.

As you can see inside the gesture detector, if the EditorMode is EDIT_MODE and the isEraserPainter is true I am trying to cleanup the previously drawn points with BlendMode. So a lot of points will be drawn.

I have seen articles and posts on stack overflow but none of them included any sample code or good explanation as of yet.

Comment: I wouldn't say ten. After about 80-90 points it'll start lagging. I will add the approx numbers in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe instead of using `canvas.drawLine` for every segment, create a new [path](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path-class.html) (before the loop) and add each segment with [`path.lineTo`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/lineTo.html). After the loop draw the whole path by using `canvas.drawPath`.

This will result in only one (complex but highly optimized) draw-call per frame instead of n.

This has the additional benefit that you can simply swap `lineTo` with something more complex like `quadraticBezierTo` to smooth out the path.

---

you would have to group your points into paths with corresponding blend mode though..

also my inner programmer cries a little when i see  `? true : false` ;)

Comment: Hey thanks I have added the solution code as answer

Answer (score 0):

The final solution following @HannesH's answer is:

```
class BrushPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<PainterPoint> points;

  BrushPainter({required this.points});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    Path path = Path();
    bool isNewLine = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      final currentPoint = points[i];

      if (currentPoint.isEnd) {
        if (!isNewLine) {
          canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
          path.reset();
          isNewLine = true;
        }
      } else {
        if (isNewLine) {
          path.moveTo(currentPoint.offset.dx, currentPoint.offset.dy);
          isNewLine = false;
        } else {
          path.lineTo(currentPoint.offset.dx, currentPoint.offset.dy);
        }

        paint.color = currentPoint.color;
        paint.strokeWidth = currentPoint.strokeSize;
        paint.blendMode = currentPoint.blendMode;
      }
    }

    if (!isNewLine) {
      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```